# Bumped questions after retagging

Tags: discussion, tagging

In the last few days there has been a very welcomed effort to clean up some tags by hand.

The problem is that the front page has only so many slots, and many questions gets pushed back due to retag bumps.

I find myself browsing questions from August whose OP hardly visits the site, or there is a very good accepted answer. Things which should really remain in the archive, rather than being popped to the actual list of questions.

Any suggestions what should we (as a community) do? Feature request of some sort? Perhaps show leniency in retagged old questions?

Comment: I think the system as it currently works is the least bad possibility.  It's important for retagged questions to come to the top so that other users can see the retagging and comment or act if they don't agree with the retagging.

Comment: @Isaac: I tend to agree with this notion. Then perhaps there should be a separate page for extremely old and retagged questions for users interested in that retags to consider, perhaps allow them to show on the front page of a user if the retag was into one of their favorite tags or something like that. This would prevent the kind of flood I was talking about as well it will allow those who actually care to do something about it in a more proficient way.

Comment: I admit I have been doing some of these for the "recursive" tag. My solution was to do just one at a time, and wait for it to fall of the main page before I do another. But only some of the questions with this tag need to be retagged, and it seems better than flooding the main page with them.

Comment: This is not a huge problem. I agree that it is annoying to come to the site, and see ten top entries being this kind of edits of an eager beaver forumite - apparently going after a Strunk&White and/or Copy Editor badge. Nothing really wrong about that, because it is a service to our site, so no names :-). Ideally this would happen when I'm sound asleep, but this is a 24/7 site, so somebody is going to get annoyed no matter when you do this :-) Clicking *newest* as opposed to *active* helps, I think?

Answer (score 8):

Generally, if you need to affect more than ... say ... ~10 questions in a retag, I would ask here on a meta for a moderator to do it as a *rename* or *merge* which does not bump questions.

It's really a question of volume.

Comment: unfortunately the situation described by Asaf was precisely a case in which a mass `rename` or `merge` wouldn've have worked. (As an aside: is there a way to use the rename/merge tool to delete a tag from the system?)