# Retagging causes bumping

Tags: feature-request, tagging, bumping, retagging

The issue of questions bumping after retagging has come up [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/bumped-questions-after-retagging) and on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59428/please-prevent-adding-removing-changing-tags-from-bumping-them-to-the-front-page).

I have a specific suggestion: disable bumping for users with high enough reputation (10k, 15k or 20k), or at least for moderators.

The main reason which is given for this bumping is that retagging might be erroneous, but I think that high-rep users can be trusted.

Comment: General comment. In the past, the appropriate response to this question would have been "ask it on meta.SO," but SE has informed the moderators that they look at site-specific metas often enough that this is unnecessary. Ask away. Spread the word.

Comment: It's here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93742/disabling-bumping-for-retags-by-hi-rep-users.

Comment: Ah, just realized I wasn't suppose to ask it on meta.SO - oh, well.

Comment: although high rep users can certainly be trusted, they can also makes mistakes (we're human anyway).

Comment: @LieRyan Indeed, I've seen many mistaggged posts by high rep users. There is not necessarily any correlation between a one-dimensional measure such as "rep" and breadth or depth of mathematical knowledge (which are both required for proper tagging).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any major retagging event should be coordinated here, on Meta, because:

1. This leaves a record of the reasoning behind the mass-retagging, and provides a venue for other users to discuss, dispute, or volunteer to participate in it.
2. ...provides a heads-up for moderators, so that they can help out (by merging tags when possible, or by simply retagging along with everyone else).
3. ...provides a heads-up for Stack Exchange, so that we can provide assistance and advice.

We don't want to just *disable* bumping for any user, since this leaves the door open for someone with a bright idea to really make a mess of things without being noticed. I've personally observed otherwise-savvy, experienced users on other sites decide they had created some brilliant new taxonomy, and tear apart the existing structure to make it fit their own preferences - this can be... problematic.

So the best advice I have for now is to get organized, and get as many willing users involved in these retagging efforts as possible - so if you must disturb the main page, you're not doing it for *very long*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a mass-retagging is taking place right now. Oh, how I wish this did not bump the questions or at least it was signaled somehow.

This is related to [Question owner: author or editor?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/question-owner-author-or-editor).

Comment: Oops. I've been limiting myself so that no more than 5 appears on the front page at one time. But I hadn't noticed that Henning and t.b. also doing some retagging (of their own initiative) at the same time. Were there more in addition to those?

Comment: @WillieWong, I haven't been keeping track. It was just my impression after clicking on several "new" posts just to see that they had been retagged. No harm done.

Comment: Actually, it _would_ be nice if on the front page it is shown what the nature of the latest activity is: edit, new answer, or retag.

Comment: @WillieWong, that's my whole point, yes. Perhaps you could ask the SE team?

Comment: Well, questions with higher number of views are "usual suspect" to be older questions recently bumped - this is what I checked on the front page when I planned to retag several question. Also when retagging questions, experienced users tend to notice details like non-descriptive title, minor TeX issues, typos etc.; hence retagging can quite often be accompanied by editing the post, too.

Comment: This feature request is, to some extent, related to @Willie's suggestion about latest activity. (It's about possibility to customize which information is shown about the question.)

Comment: Now I found out that I've forgotten to put the link in my last comment - now I'm not able to find the thread again :-(

Comment: I guess it might have been link to [Add link to most recent activity of a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14562/183484). I have learned from that thread that by clicking on the time of the last activity I can find out, what was the last thing done with the question. But the answer I've linked to suggests that it would be nice to see the type of activity even without the need of clicking on the timestamp.