# Too many ellipsoid questions being bumped to the front page.

Tags: discussion, tagging

I was browsing the front page and noticed that the first 20ish questions were all old questions, edited to include the newly created [ellipsoids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipsoids) tag.

I was under the impression that there was some limit to editing tags in this way? I don't feel that this is productive to the site's usability.

It seems from a brief meta [review](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/bumped-questions-after-retagging) that this seems to be the community consensus as well.

Comment: What exactly is the point of this meta post? What do you want to discuss?

Comment: @quid I was wondering whether this had somehow become permissible behavior, and if not, how should it be handled?

Comment: The limit is agreed upon informally. You can inform the user by a comment (comment notification works for editors) that they might  want to check the etiquette on editing multiple post or you can inform the moderators via a flag on an affected post.

Comment: I have posted a related request [originally on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27492/limit-for-number-of-questions-where-tag-can-be-added-by-tag-creator-soon-after-t) and later on [meta.se]: [Do not allow massive retagging by the tag-creator shortly after creation of a new tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306062). You can find several posts pointing out similar problems [in this list](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/27492).

Comment: Mea culpa. I have edited dozens of questions today. Ellipsoids aren't particularly special.

Comment: @amWhy Does editing tag descriptions push questions to the front page?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo editing rather many posts in a shorter period of time can be seen as generally problematic. An issue sometimes not taken into account is a concentration of such activity on some tags can have more impact for users following that tag then one might expect. I also understand that if one has a bit of spare time to donate to the site to improve it, which is great, this might occur in blocks and result in a peak of activity. There is balance to be found, it is not clear where it is. I'd say one should strive not to have more than 3 to 5 posts on the frontpage at any given time.

Comment: @quid When I make a few edits in a row and push a few old questions to the front page, I tend to edit new questions, too.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo (Somehow orthogonal to the complaint here) There is another issue of editing too many posts too early: if the community decided that the new tag should better be removed, then that would be more jobs than necessary. I think there are several people taking a close look on new tags. It would be great if you can wait for (e.g.) a week before massive retagging.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo 20ish is more than a few.

Comment: @amWhy I have edited some 70 MSE posts today.

Comment: Is there a way that the algorithm can be changed so that if an edit does nothing more than change the tags then the question is not bumped? That seems like a very straightforward solution.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish things like that are proposed *often*, yet it is not really desirable that such edits pass unnoticed.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Also it would require petitioning SE devs to implement it, which makes it much less straightforward.

Comment: I have found the sheer number of questions being bumped to the front page due to edits with tags very annoying, both here and on hsm.stackexchange. At times it feels like an abuse of the ability of being able to add or edit tags and I have been tempted to suggest that certain people who are editing tags excessively take a time out on that for a while.

Comment: @KCd Thank you for the kind words. Why very annoying? Why do you care about what is on the front page or not?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I care a lot, as it means that questions that were asked more recently get buried. I had to dig through more than 3 pages of questions to find a new question at the time of your edits. That is not good.

Comment: @DonThousand I find it **very hard** to believe that 70 edits in one day can create the mayhem you have described. Making such accusations under a pseudonym is not very wise. My edits are public and can be audited. And some people can find new questions without visiting Math SE.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I haven't described any mayhem. I keep a pseudonym since I've been doxxed on this site previously. I don't appreciate the condescension. You are getting this feedback because your edits are public.

Comment: @DonThousand You don't appreciate condescension and I don't appreciate false accusations.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't understand why you are so fired up about this. This thread has clearly shown a decent amount of active MSE users found your editing somewhat problematic in nature, and you continue to deny the effects of said edits. In doing so, you are picking fights with several users in this thread. What do you seek to gain from this?

Comment: @DonThousand Deny which effects? The factual ones? Or the ones you invented?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo recently it seems the front page has numerous old questions bumped there due to edits, often tag edits from you. It is considered bad etiquette to make trivial edits to a question because, as an answer to meta question 23056 says, a trivial edit "creates noise on the front page, and it is unfair to the other users whose questions (or the questions which they answered) are pushed from the front page by the bumps."  Perhaps an edit tag is not trivial, but since you now know that tag edits bump a question to the front page, please keep the bump effect in mind when editing.

Comment: @KCd I do keep that in mind, which is why I edit new questions after editing old questions. At least on Math SE, where the front page is fast-moving.

Comment: Don, if the concern is not to be able to find new question, recall that it is possible to browse the site in view "newest"  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest where only new questions are shown. cc @KCd

Comment: @quid Very true. I do prefer the quality of the main page over the newest page, though. Regardless, I hold no hard feelings towards anyone, as after all, this question was meant to improve my understanding of the way that this site works. Thanks for your time again.

Comment: @mjw I think we do not need an "ellipsoids" tag on meta...

Comment: @ArcticChar, but isn't this a "meta-ellipsoids" question?

Comment: @ArcticChar Next week: Too many meta-ellipsoid questions bumped to the first page :P

Comment: @quid Not as bad as the incident behind this post, but a similar event happened yesterday. A bit frustrating, especially as some of the edited posts were closed.

Comment: @DonThousand if you did not do so already please raise a flag on an affected post.